# Best way to return duplicate elements in an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the way I am using to return duplicate elements..  But I am facing most dangerous performance issues like browser close etc when my array have large number of items with long texts..

```
var arr = [9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];
var sorted_arr = arr.sort();
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
  if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
     results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
  }
}
alert(results);
```

Please suggest me a best way of doing this

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array

Comment: Are the array keys only integers? Also, how long is your real array and the items in it?

Comment: @Saifuddin Holy crap it's even the same array. This leads me to believe it's a question about consumption, rather than the technique.

Comment: Not a duplicate question as much as a question on a solution of another question. Also, this algorithm has a potential bug: it will return N-1 copies of K if the input contains N copies of K. This bug is currently hidden because the test case has no more than two of an item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i don't get exactly what you want, but if you need to return duplicates you could use a cache object. this works with number or string or whatever.

```
var arr = [9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];
var cache = {};
var results = [];
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
  if(cache[arr[i]] === true){
      results.push(arr[i]);
   }else{
       cache[arr[i]] = true;
   }

}
console.log(results);//returns an array with 9 and 4
```

Of course you can do other things like deleting multiple items etc. etc.

EDIT - i've written a blog entry on [how to remove duplicates from an array](http://newcodeandroll.blogspot.it/2012/01/how-to-find-duplicates-in-array-in.html)

Answer (score 6):

We have array `filter`, and also `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`,
so you can return the duplicates without doing the sort.

```
var results, arr = [9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 7];

results = arr.filter(function(itm, i){
    return arr.lastIndexOf(itm)== i && arr.indexOf(itm)!= i;
});

console.log(results);

/*  returned value: (Array)
9,4
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Nicola's solution doesn't work for you (since it uses about as much memory as the original solution: two elements stored per element in the input, worst-case), you can use the slower process of repeatedly searching your input.

This requires the `Array.indexOf` method from ECMAScript 5. A lot of browsers have it. For alternatives, see [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript).

```
var arr = [9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];
var results = [];
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length - 1; i < len; i++) {
  if((results.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1) && (arr.indexOf(arr[i], i + 1) != -1)) {
      results.push(arr[i]);
   }
}
console.log(results);
```

This uses no more memory than the input `arr` plus the output `results`, but it's an O(N^2) algorithm and doesn't have to modify `arr`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method relies on a sort, which may or may not be one reason you run out of space/time.

The canonical way to remove duplicates is to keep a hash map of the keys (an object in JS). The object keys you get back won't necessarily be in the order you want; you don't specify if you want the results ordered as well, but they are now.

You could `null` out the original array, since you no longer require it; when it gets collected is up to the JS engine though.

You could remove duplicates "in place" by keeping a "current index" into the sorted array, and increment it only when you move a non-duplicated element "down" from the counter index, then truncate the array that you return.

Combining the last two techniques should mean that in general you'll only have a single array with a valid reference.

*Edit* Example. Setting `length` explicitly, as `.slice()` creates a new array.

```
var have = {};
var arr = [9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];
arr = arr.sort();

for (var rIdx = 0, i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (have[arr[i]]) {
        arr[rIdx++] = arr[i];
    } else {
        have[arr[i]] = true;
    }
}

arr.length = rIdx;
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: More or less what i wrote! :)

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti Not quite; you still have an additional array. Looks like you're gonna win anyway ;)

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ Could you please provide me some example code. :-)

Comment: @SoI Updated answer; you'd have to test to see if it actually fixes the problem, though--I'm testing on the tiny little array.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ yes,  you could get rid of that second array, but i think it's a viable solution: it keeps things simple and clear. That's just my opinion of course! :)

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti Agreed, but if the issue actually *is* resource consumption, games must be played :)

Comment: Why not use `arr = arr.sort();` in place of lines 2 and 3?

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Because when I do it ends up empty.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Nope, that was a typo--I just didn't; no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the array using [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), including elements with a different first occurrence index and acting as the last occurrence in the array.

```js
const returnDuplicates = arr => arr.filter((item, index) => arr.indexOf(item) !== index && arr.lastIndexOf(item) === index);

const array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, true, true, "hello", "hello"];
console.log(returnDuplicates(array));
```